# How does $\mathfrak g'$ be an ideal of $\mathfrak g\ $?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

[image]

In the first paragraph of the above proof how does the author conclude that $\mathfrak g'$ is an ideal of $\mathfrak g\ $? Could anyone please shed some light on it?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true since $\mathfrak g'$ contains $[\mathfrak g, \mathfrak g]$, so taking the Lie bracket of any element in $\mathfrak g'$ with any element in $\mathfrak g$ will result in something which belongs to $[\mathfrak g, \mathfrak g]$, so it will surely belong to $\mathfrak g'$.

Comment: Hmm understand. Could you also please describe equation (6.1)?

Comment: The first equality is by definition of $v^k$ (here I guess the author identifies $x$ with $\rho(x)$ for convenience). The next step is by definition of the commutator (expand the commutator and see that you get the same thing). The last step is due to the induction assumption.

Comment: I don't understand the second step. We should have $\rho (h) v^k = \rho ([h,x]) v^{k-1}.$ Then what is the commutator relation. I only know that $[h,x] = -[x,h].$

Comment: @AnilBagchi You have the equality $hx=xh+ [h,x]$. This can be verified by just expanding the expression for the commutator and letting things cancel.

Comment: What is $hx$? The product in the Lie algebra is given by the Lie bracket. Am I missing something?

Comment: How $hx$ and $xh$ are defined?

Comment: @AnilBagchi In the Lie algebra, yes. But in this line the author identifies $x$ with $\rho(x)$ and similarly with $h$, so when you write $x,h$ you actually mean their representation as matrices. When you move to the representation, the Lie bracket is replaced with a commutator, and the usual product of matrices is defined.

Comment: I am confused. So $hx = \rho ([h,x])\ $? I don't think so. Please elaborate instead of writing in words.

Comment: Here $[h,x]$ means $\rho ([h,x]).$ What does $hx$ mean here? The author is very unclear about it. Does it mean $\rho (h) \rho (x)\ $? We should have $\rho ([h,x]) = \rho (h) \rho (x).$

Comment: @AnilBagchi In $6.1$, every time the author writes $x$ or $h$, he actually means $\rho(x),\rho(h)$, and when he writes $[x,h]$ he actually means $[\rho(x),\rho(h)]$, which is by definition $\rho(x)\rho(h)-\rho(h)\rho(x)$. The author does this for convenience, although he should have written it more explicitly (maybe he writes this somewhere else in the chapter).

Comment: @AnilBagchi Where does he write something like this? He only writes that
$\rho(h)\rho(x) = \rho(x)\rho(h) + [\rho(h), \rho(x)]$, which is an identity for matrices.

Comment: Yes I got it. I misread your above comment and that's the reason for such confusion. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry I want to ask another question. Please don't mind. How do the author take $v,v^1, \cdots, v^n$ as a basis. Are the vectors necessarily linearly independent?